# Batch file to split filenames and use part for new subdir to move into

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a few thousand photographs in a single folder all named with the pattern `persons name - location.jpg`, e.g. `John Doe - Mountain.jpg`. I'm looking for a batch file that will create folders based on the first part of the file name and move that file and all of the other matching file names into that folder, giving an end result of all of John Doe's pictures in his folder.

Comment: A batch file or a shell script? bash is *nix, but batch files are Windows.

Comment: I need a windows batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*.jpg" '
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%p IN ("%%a") DO (
  echo(MD "%destdir%\%%p"
  echo(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%p"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Note that the terminating space in the directory name is of no relevance.

Comment: Is there 1 line that I could use in linux to do the same thing